# How to stream Azure Blob to AWS S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage

I need to copy a large Azure Blob to AWS S3 without keeping a copy of it in the memory. After some Googling I have found a bunch of examples that I combined in the following script. This still loads data into memory though. Is there a good way to avoid it?

```
import boto3
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

with io.BytesIO() as input_stream, io.BytesIO() as output_stream:
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str=AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING,
        container_name=container,
        blob_name=filename,
    )
    blob_client.download_blob().readinto(input_stream)

    input_stream.seek(0)
    shutil.copyfileobj(input_stream, output_stream)
    output_stream.seek(0)

    boto3.resource("s3").Object(BUCKET_NAME, s3_key).put(Body=output_stream)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't tell me anything. How do you manage to transfer a synchronous broadcast to non-syncusers? Buffer memory is mandatory in streams. He makes hardware even if you don't do it. You cannot provide streaming without resource management. ((delay*FPS) == BUFFER ).(On your code already got  duplicate data,You cannot read data that does not exist. If you read the data, you'll have two data.)

Comment: I am not familiar with Azure Blob [my question may not make sense], but I am with AWS, specifically S3. Recently I have mounted an S3 bucket as a file system and it works perfectly in a similar situation to what you describe. Would that work for you?

Comment: @JamesMead The code will be run as lambda.

Answer (score 3):

The copy of the blob is in the memory, because you seem to be reading it in one go. You're initializing two instances of `io.BytesIO`, but then you're reading the entire blob using `blob_client.download_blob().readinto(input_stream)`.

What I think you should try instead is reading (and putting) chunks of the blob, one chunk at a time, avoiding reading the entirety of it to memory.

On the upload side (s3), you can approach the issue in two ways. You can either:

- Use S3 partial (multipart) upload mechanism (using `.upload()` to initiate, and then `.upload_part()` to upload each part (chunk), or
- Provide a file-like object to `.upload_fileobj()` that would be responsible for providing a chunk at a time

As far as I can tell, seems like `blob_client.download_blob()` already returns a file-like object called `StorageStreamDownloader`, that implements a `chunks()` method. I can't find proper documentation for it, [but according to the source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/_download.py#L428), seems like it's returning an iterator that you can use.

Therefore, consider something like this (I don't have access to any azure/s3 service at this very moment, so this code might not work out of the box):

```
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig, S3Transfer

blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_str=AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING,
    container_name=container,
    blob_name=filename,
)
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

mpu = s3.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=s3_key)
mpu_id = mpu["UploadId"]

blob = blob_client.download_blob()
for part_num, chunk in enumerate(blob.chunks()):
    s3.upload_part(
        Body=chunk,
        Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
        Key=s3_key,
        UploadId=mpu_id,
        PartNumber=part_num,
    )
```

Like I mentioned - I have no access to any blob storage/s3 resource right now, so I eyeballed the code. But the general idea should be the same. By using `.chunks()` of the blob, you should only fetch a small chunk of the data into the memory, upload it (using MPU) to S3 and discard immediatelly.

Comment: Was this ever verified as a workable streamer? If not, I'd be willing to bounty up a couple hundred points for something verified. My biggest question is: How does `boto3` know the stream is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the *samu* answer here is a working example, there was a missing part related to complete the multipart upload

```
def copy_from_azure_to_s3(conn_str:str,container_name:str,file_name:str,bucket_name:str,s3):

    #initiate Azure client
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str=con_string,
        container_name=container_name,
        blob_name=file_name,
        max_chunk_get_size=50*1024*1024 #min size for multipart upload is 5MB, it needs to be higher than that
    )

    #define multipart upload
    mpu = s3.create_multipart_upload(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
    mpu_id = mpu["UploadId"]

    blob = blob_client.download_blob()

    #store info about individual parts
    etags=[]

    #stream it to s3
    for part_num, chunk in enumerate(blob.chunks(), start=1):
        response= s3.upload_part(
            Body=chunk,
            Bucket=bucket_name,
            Key=file_name,
            UploadId=mpu_id,
            PartNumber=part_num,
        )
        etags.append({'ETag': response['ETag'],'PartNumber':part_num})

    #finish the upload
    s3.complete_multipart_upload(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=file_name,
        UploadId=mpu_id,
        MultipartUpload={
            'Parts': etags
        },

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one very simple way to do this

```
import temp

blob_client = ...
s3_client = ...

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp_file:
    for chunk in blob_client.download_blob().chunks():
        # download in chunk and flush it into hard disk from memory
        temp_file.write(chunk)
        temp_file.flush()

    # the below upload automatically handles the multi-part uploading
    s3_client.upload(temp_file.name, s3_bucket, s3_key)
```